# Rails routing, deep nesting for external resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I understand that it's a good practice to only include in the URL the parameters needed to determine the object of the model.
If I have 2 models, Post and Comment... a Post has many comments and a comment belongs to one post. A URL for a comment can be

```
/comment/:comment_id
```

and from associations I can determine which Post it belongs to but
Some rails apps need to access external resources(Via APIs for example). If the rails app needs to replicate a part of another external source, what is the right way to handle URLs and routing?
If for example a post has some comments, The URL for a comment can be

```
/post/:post_id/comment/:comment_id
```

or

```
/comment/:comment_id
```

The latter has one disadvantage which is that I can't determine which post it belongs to if the API of the external source doesn't determine that and this would cause some problems with navigation through the app but it's a short URL and allows the user to easily manipulate the URL to get another comment(which I see as an advantage). At the same time using the first(long) link would make the URL so long but I can know which post it belongs to.

The only solution I can think of is to make both possible but the user would never know that the short one exists if I make the long one the default. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I always use the longer / spelled-out version myself. I don't mind that it's long and I can only see good things come from it as you're discovering here. I also think it's an advantage because then you can do things like this:

```
post = Post.find_by_id(params[:post_id])
comment = post.comments.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

The point being that you can't go "`comment` fishing" this way. You have to have the right `post` context in order to get at a specific `comment`. This may not matter a whole lot if comments aren't at all sensitive, but there are many thing in a web app that may be. So scoping finds by a root object (like `post` here) allows a quick permissions check that can be reused and without having to check on parent objects.

Anyway, that's my 2 cents. I never understood why people take offense to the longer urls. If they work for you then don't be afraid to use them!